# Duplicate by using LINQ with mulitiple OR creteria

Tags: c#, linq

I can retrieve duplicate by using this query:

```
var duplicates = grpDupes
    .GroupBy(i => new { i.Email })
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

But i am interested to find duplicates by using either `Email` or `Address` or xyz.
If i modify above query

```
GroupBy(i => new { i.Email, i.Address })
```

then it becomes AND condition, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `EXISTS` in SQL which is `Any` in LINQ:

```
var duplicates = grpDupes
    .Where(i => (i.Email.Trim() != "" || i.Address.Trim() != "")  && grpDupes
        .Any(i2 => i.ID != i2.ID && 
            ((i.Email.Trim()   != "" && i.Email   == i2.Email) || 
             (i.Address.Trim() != "" && i.Address == i2.Address))));
```

Note that i've used `ID` as the primary key column. If you don't have one you need to use the column(s) that you want to use as identifier.

If you use as database driven LINQ provider like LINQ-To-SQL or LINQ-To-Entities this is efficient.

Comment: This seems working , anyone  tell me why should i not use this?

Comment: can we improve this by ignoring blank emails or address in       i.Email == i2.Email  || i.Address == i2.Address). If emails in both records r empty then it also consider it as duplicate

Comment: @user3636316: i have edited my answer to provide a way that should work with all LINQ providers (as opposed to `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` for example).

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the overloaded method which accepts an `EqualityComparer`.

```
    /// <summary>
/// Factory class which creates an EqualityComparer based on lambda expressions.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of which a new equality comparer is to be created.</typeparam>
public static class EqualityComparerFactory<T>
{
    private class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        private readonly Func<T, int> _getHashCodeFunc;
        private readonly Func<T, T, bool> _equalsFunc;

        public MyComparer(Func<T, T, bool> equalsFunc, Func<T, int> getHashCodeFunc = null)
        {
            _getHashCodeFunc = getHashCodeFunc ?? (a=>0);
            _equalsFunc = equalsFunc;
        }

        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            return _equalsFunc(x, y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T obj)
        {
            return _getHashCodeFunc(obj);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an <see cref="IEqualityComparer{T}" /> based on an equality function and optionally on a hash function.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="equalsFunc">The equality function.</param>
    /// <param name="getHashCodeFunc">The hash function.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A typed Equality Comparer.
    /// </returns>
    public static IEqualityComparer<T> CreateComparer(Func<T, T, bool> equalsFunc, Func<T, int> getHashCodeFunc = null)
    {
        ArgumentValidator.NotNull(() => equalsFunc);

        return new MyComparer(equalsFunc, getHashCodeFunc);
    }
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
        var comparer = EqualityComparerFactory<YourClassHere>.CreateComparer((a, b) => a.Address == b.Address || a.Email == b.Email);

        data.GroupBy(a => a, comparer);
```

Comment: It will throw `ArgumentNullException` without hashcode method isn't it?

Comment: yeah sorry, i picked a newer verion. hold on. ... Done

Comment: Bit of a violation of YAGNI as an answer to this question

Comment: Thanks there are two issues ,  ArgumentValidator does not exist in current context
does not take 2 paramters
 var comparer = EqualityComparerFactory<RetrieveDuplicateLead>.CreateComparer(null, (a, b) => a.Address == b.Address || a.Email == b.Email );

Comment: Sorry for that one. this one originates from a framework i am using.<br/>To the second issue: Just leave out the null argument.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep this very simple by using `.ToLookup()`.

How about this?

```
var emailLookup = grpDupes.ToLookup(x => x.Email);
var addressLookup = grpDupes.ToLookup(x => x.Address);

var duplicates = grpDupes
    .Where(x =>
        emailLookup[x.Email].Count() > 1 || addressLookup[x.Address].Count() > 1);
```